# Buildfire: PHP API To send notifications

Tags: notifications, push, buildfire

I am using php api to send push notifications to users using docs provided here
https://sdk.buildfire.com/AWSGatewayPublicAPI/#/push_notifications/post_push_notifications_schedule

Is there a way I can send notification to all devices which has app installed but not logged in?

Thanks,
Chandresh

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to send a push notification to all devices, the group_id is required.
but you can create a service in your plugin and subscribe the users to your plugin group, this way you can send a PN to all subscribed users.

Comment: Right now I am using https://sdk.buildfire.com/AWSGatewayPublicAPI/#/user/get_user_search to make my api calls in php. Please let me know if you have any other documentation for php api calls.
1. How I can know when user installs the application in their device without logged into application so I can subscribe him to particular group?
2. Which api I should call to subscribe him to particular group and where I can create a default group.
3. Is there a way so when user installs the application to their device, it goes to particular group automatically?